# Are unserializable members of serializable objects serialized?

Tags: c#, serialization

Say I have the following classes:

```
[Serializable]
public class foo
{
    public bar randomBar;

    // required serialization methods would go here
}
```

And

```
public class bar
{
    int barInt;

    // constructors and such
}
```

`bar` is not serializable, but `foo` is. When I serialize a `foo` object, will its `randomBar` be serialized with it, or will it cause an error?

Comment: The simplest answer would be to try it and see, surely. (I'd expect it to give an error...)

Comment: Yeah it doesn't work. I just marked `bar` with `[Serializable]`, and that fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The serializer throws an error. Try the following in LinqPad:

```
void Main()
{
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    var formatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.Serialize(stream, new Foo { bar = new Bar { barInt = 2 } });

}

// Define other methods and classes here
[Serializable]
public class Foo { public Bar bar; }

public class Bar { public int barInt; }
```

The error is:

```
Type 'UserQuery+Bar' in Assembly 'query_nsalab, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.
```

Comment: I just made `bar` serializable. Thanks for your help though!